# How to update state inside array of objects on specific filed which is also array as on below code in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Initial State

```
 const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    {
      name: "",
      city_pictures: [
        {
          file: "",
          type: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

Updating The Outer list(list of cities)

```
const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([
      ...inputList,
      {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        price: 0,
        avaliable_stock: 0,
        pictures: [
          {
            file: "",
            type: "",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  };
```

Please help how I would updates pictures inside a specific object by the index of the object(city) with this:-

```
{
   file: "",
   type: "",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you can't mutate state. When you use setState, basically it deletes the old one replacing it with a new one. So you can try passing the state to a variable then modify it.
Ex:

```
let tempInputList = inputList;
//do what you need to in here;
setInputList(tempInputList);
```

Edit:

as Ivan pointed out in the comment. You should create a new object by mapping it to tempInputList. So the code can be:

```
    let tempInputList = inputList.map(x=>x);
    //do what you need to in here;
    setInputList(tempInputList);
```

Comment: thank you so much. I now see I will use the temp state hack thanks

Comment: this will not work , as objects are passed by reference `tempInputList` is the same as `inputList` they are pointing to the same object in memory

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing it like this:

```js
let data = [
  { name: "a", pictures: { a: "a", b: "a" } },
  { name: "b", pictures: { a: "b", b: "b" } },
  { name: "c", pictures: { a: "c", b: "c" } }
];

const index = 1; // change {name:b} object
data = [
  ...data.slice(0, index),
  { ...data[index], pictures: { a: "d", b: "d" } },
  ...data.slice(index + 1)
];

// { name: "a", pictures: { a: "a", b: "a" } },
// { name: "b", pictures: { a: "d", b: "d" } },
// { name: "c", pictures: { a: "c", b: "c" } }

console.log(data);
```

What we are doing here is creating a new array by spreading the old array up to the `index`, then inserting the new data at `index` (by spreading the index, and only changing the `address`) and then, spreading the array from `index` to the end of the array.